# receive payments with paypal

Tags: php, api, cakephp, paypal, payment

I'm creating a really small website where I'll sell some products. 
I need this website to show the available products, the users can add to the cart, and pay at the end, then I'll send the product for them by my self. It's a really small business.

I was taking a look at the paypal options and I didn't understand very well how it works.
For what I understand, with a free account I can only use their buttons, but I can't have a dynamic solution where I can manage my products on my website (look's like I need to add the products information like name and price on their website ).

What I wanted to do was just use my own website to handle this very simple store/products, and at the end, the user click on a CheckOut button, and Then I redirect the user to a paypal page where they can pay for the total value and then paypal redirect them back to me ( as a free account or at least with the 5$ account ).

Is that possible?

By the way I'm using CakePHP to build that, and I already have the website built with this framework, and to build what I need it's more than enough, I don't really need any solution like magento or others eCommerce platform.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Paypal's free account then your visitor will leave your website, go to Paypal's website to make the payment, and then return to your website.  Paypals paid version allows you to keep your visitor on your page, but you have to program you site to work with their API.  Plus the cost can add up.  Paypal also has other service other than just buttons.  For instance they have a shopping cart too, but here again your vistor will leave your website to go to Paypals site to add the items to the shopping cart.

Another company that you might want to look at is https://stripe.com/  here you keep the vistor on your site as well as only paying per transaction rather than a monthly fee like at Paypal.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manage your items and inventory from your website and not enter everything into buttons at PayPal.com, I would suggest that you use Express Checkout. Express Checkout is also a free service and allows you to send all of the payments details to PayPal via API and PayPal will authenticate and allow your buyers to select shipping details. The user can then be redirected back to your website to complete their order.

You can find additional information here: https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/express-checkout/gs_expresscheckout

Thanks,